# How to deploy to Snow Leopard with ARC enabled

Tags: cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, automatic-ref-counting

I have an OSX app that I would like to migrate to ARC. Everything works fine if I set the base SDK to 10.7. But when I set it to 10.6 it does not work ( because it does not find _objc_release etc.). So how do I deploy my app to 10.6 with ARC enabled?

Answer (score 12):

You set the SDK to 10.7 but the Deployment Target to 10.6.

Keep in mind:

> While it's possible to build programs using ARC that run on Mac OS X 10.6 and iOS 4, zeroing weak references are not available on those OSes. All weak references must be __unsafe_unretained here. Because non-zeroing weak references are so dangerous, this limitation significantly decreases the attractiveness of ARC on those OSes in my view.

Source: [Automatic Reference Counting](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html)

Comment: 10.6 and iOS 4.0 are the earliest platforms, but as catlan indicates, ARC has a severe restriction there.  10.7 and iOS 5 are the earliest platforms where ARC can operate in entirety.  I think I will go with ARC for our 10.6 deployment since it is new as you can disable ARC on a per file basis.

Comment: My 2 cents: Accessing references not knowing if they are released or not (using the __weak functionality) seems a bit weird to me. You are supposed to know the lifetime of your objects, even more if you do not own the object you are sending messages to. For me personally not having __weak is a non-issue. Before ARC you weren't sending messages to objects either without knowing if the object you didn't own still exists. IMO (except for a few exceptions) it is a bad coding practice.

Comment: Joris: __weak is for back pointers. Otherwise you get retain circles. For that, it's much safer than relying on everybody manually zeroing out their references. But yeah, in most other cases it's definitely a code smell.

Answer (score 7):

You might find PLWeakCompatibility useful. It allows you to use __weak variables on iOS 4 and OS X 10.6.

Source code here: https://github.com/plausiblelabs/PLWeakCompatibility
More info at http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/introducing-plweakcompatibility.html