# Symbol not found: _objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue in ARC-enabled dylib

Tags: objective-c, macos, automatic-ref-counting

I have an ARC-enabled application which dynamically loads a dylib via `dlopen`. The dylib is also ARC-enabled. Both are compiled with the MacOSX SDK 10.7 with deployment target 10.6.

At the `dlopen`, I get:

```
Symbol not found: _objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue
  Referenced from: /Users/bea/Downloads/MusicPlayer.app/Contents/Resources/Python/_guiCocoaCommon.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

This is kind of right because `_objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue` is not in `/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib` on MacOSX 10.6. But where is it?

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It's not part of OS X 10.6, so it's simply *not* there at all. You would have to write a shim that provides these functions on 10.6 to get your code to work.

Comment: @JustSid: But the rest of the application, which uses ARC, works on OSX 10.6. It only fails at the `dlopen`.

Comment: yeah, I did some digging after posting that comment and it appears like Xcode auto links a static library called ARClite that provides the symbols. Apparently not for your dynamic library though (although it should, if it has 10.6 as deployment target). Quite interesting, sadly I don't have a 10.6 machine to dig deeper into this.

Comment: Does `libarclite_macosx.a` really provide that symbol? I only see `___arclite_objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue`. I tried to statically link `libarclite_macosx.a` against my dylib but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Albert, is your entire project using ARC, or do you still have parts that use manual retain/release?

Comment: @l'L'l: There are parts (other dylibs) which use manual retain/release. Those are completely independent though.

Comment: @Albert, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10763668/499581); hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: @l'L'l: I already have ARC enabled in the main target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dlopen` I used was with the `RTLD_NOW` flag. (I used it from within Python via `ctypes.CDLL` / `ctypes._dlopen` and `RTLD_NOW` is forced there.)

I guess you must use `RTLD_LAZY` on MacOSX because of this. When I use `RTLD_LAZY`, everything works fine (so far). <del>It looks like as if the symbol `_objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue` is actually not used. So I wonder why it is there at all. Maybe this is a bug in Apples compiler.</del> **Edit:** I think this explanation was wrong. I looked at the disassembly and it is used in one of my methods. But I guess it is replaced by the existing `___arclite_objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue` at runtime which is also in the Dylib (so I guess libarclite_macosx.a is always automatically statically linked to it).

(I opened an issue about Python [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue20276). You can see my fix [here](https://github.com/albertz/CPython/commit/7000fd4058f23da1414c24689dd151d354a387bc).)